# How to increase accuracy in SVM training and classification in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, classification, svm

I am having svm training with several images. This is my first project with SVM. I am extracting features with HOG feature extraction. Training features and label their locations 1 if it is on the horizon line, 0 if it is on the background. I have 74 images for training and 7 images for testing. Unfortunately, I can't go above 50 percent accuracy. I have changed image sizes, I have played cell sizes in feature extraction. It does not change that much. What can I try? And what is the ideal dataset number, how many images for training and testing? For example in one image it predicts all correct in next image all wrong.

This is how I am calculating accuracy;

```
%%%%% Evaluation
% Testing Data
hfsTest = vertcat(dataset.HorizonFeatsTest{:});
bfsTest = vertcat(dataset.BgFeatsTest{:});
test_data = [hfsTest;bfsTest];
% Labels
hlabelTest = ones(size(hfsTest,1),1);
blabelTest = zeros(size(bfsTest,1),1);
test_label = [hlabelTest;blabelTest];

Predict_label = vertcat(results.predicted_label{:});

acc = numel(find(Predict_label==test_label))/length(test_label);
disp(['Accuracy ', num2str(acc)]);
%done

% Training Data
hfs = vertcat(dataset.HorizonFeats{:});
bfs = vertcat(dataset.BgFeats{:});
train_data = [hfs;bfs];
% Labels
hlabel = ones(size(hfs,1),1);
blabel = zeros(size(bfs,1),1);
train_label = [hlabel;blabel];

%%%
% do training ...
svmModel = svmtrain(train_data, train_label,'BoxConstraint',2e-1);
```

and I have used Predict_label_image = svmclassify (svmModel, image_feats); for testing.

Comment: Please show how you train your SVM. Maybe you should try a grid search over the hyperparameters?

Comment: I have edited my question but I dont know if I answer your question. I have used svmtrain and svmclassify.

Comment: Did you have a look at the scale of the input features? SVM can benefit significantly from standardization http://content.iospress.com/articles/intelligent-data-analysis/ida730

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a lot of tunning. Here in the [documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) you have all the hyperparameters you can play with. I'll start with a rbf kernel and trying [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10] for BoxConstraint.

I'm afraid you can't expect svm to work if you don't try different hyperparameter configurations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How did you decide for values of BoxConstraint? Because I get this error'
Error using svmtrain (line 460)
The box constraint must be a positive numeric scalar, or a vector of positive numbers with length equal to the number of rows in
TRAINING.

Error in main2 (line 62)
svmModel = svmtrain(train_data, train_label,'BoxConstraint',[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]);

Comment: I mean you have to do different runs: svmtrain(train_data, train_label,'BoxConstraint', 0.01, 'kernel_function', 'rbf'); svmtrain(train_data, train_label,'BoxConstraint', 0.1, 'kernel_function', 'rbf'); svmtrain(train_data, train_label,'BoxConstraint', 1, 'kernel_function', 'rbf'); ...

Comment: @J63  You can also use `bayesopt` to find the optimal hyperparameters automatically: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/bayesian-optimization-case-study.html

Comment: It is interesting, nothing changes. It is always between 48 and 53. even if i put 0.01 or 100 or 0,1 not changing so much.